# Set near/far clip distance for the visualization window camera

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

When viewing an outdoor gazebo world from some distance above, I get strong Z-fighting artifacts between two ground planes located on top of each other at a distance of about 0.5 meters.
I suppose this could be fixed with a more suitable near and far clip distance for the visualization camera. Is there a way to set this distances in gazebo? Is it possible to access the camera parameters using a Gazebo-GUI-Plugin?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/13668/set-near/far-clip-distance-for-the-visualization-window-camera/) by [c_rist](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2667/c_rist/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2016-06-16

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Illuminatur](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1512/illuminatur/) on 2016-06-26**:
Hey guys,

we have also the problem with z-Fighting. Is there any possibility to modify the near clipping plane???
A solution or even some advice would be great!!

Best regards!!

**Comment by [Illuminatur](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1512/illuminatur/) on 2016-07-02**:
Are there no ideas?

Best regards.

**Comment by [yah130s](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1228/yah130s/) on 2017-05-17**:
@Illuminatur please don't try hijacking the thread, instead open a new question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It should be possible to do it from a GUI plugin. Just get the user camera:

[rendering::UserCameraPtr camera = gazebo::gui::get_active_camera();](http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/7.1.0/namespacegazebo_1_1gui.html#a1cc301f227f0717038ae271fa789bd06)

And set the new clip distances:

[camera->SetClipDist(near, far);](http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/7.1.0/classgazebo_1_1rendering_1_1Camera.html#a36b189060fbbaf495e16751364367718)

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2016-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [c_rist](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2667/c_rist/) on 2016-07-12**:
Thanks a lot, this fixes my problem.